# Pandas Dataframe to Excel - Custom Date time format not applying

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have the below dataframe `df.head()` :

|  | datetime | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-20 13:43:44.915200 | 503 |
| 1 | 2021-07-22 08:22:56.037200 | 33 |
| 2 | 2021-08-18 19:34:56.142200 | 104 |
| 4 | 2021-09-26 14:07:21.628300 | 245 |

```
df.dtypes

datetime                datetime64[ns]
qty                     float64
```

The issue I have is trying to get the format of the date-time column converted to dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss when exporting to excel.

I've tried changing the format of the dataframe column but that results in changing the datatype from datatime64[ns] to object (i.e. string), with the result that it is no longer a formatted number in Excel.
I want to keep the dataframe column as datetime64[ns] and hoping to find a solution that will format date time column in Excel as dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss, keeping it as a formatted number.

I'm currently using the below code to import the dataframe data into Excel and save it:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('outputfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_1', index=False, startrow=2)
    
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet_1']
    
    datetime_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss'})
    worksheet.set_column('A:A',None,datetime_format)
```

The code does output the data in Excel, but the dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss formatting is only being applied to column A (the date time column) before and after the actual dataframe date (I'm purposefully not writing the data until row 2).

When I inspect 'Format Cells' dialog in Excel, row 0 and row 1 of column A are being formatted as dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss. In cells of the column that have datetime values, those cells are retaining the format of the original pandas dataframe column (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:microseconds).

[image]

It seems as though the dataframe's original formatting is overwriting the custom formatting, despite the two lines of code defining and applying the custom formatting coming after the `df.to_excel()` line that writes the dataframe content to Excel.

Hoping someone might be able to spot an obvious issue here or if this is a limitation of xlsxwriter.

Comment: [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) has a `datetime_format` parameter.

Comment: Have you given thought to `deep copy`. Dataframe by its nature tends to be referential.

Comment: Note if you're using the openpyxl engine (rather than xlsxwriter as in this question), there's currently a bug which means the date_format and datetime_format parameters get ignored (so you always get the default format): https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned by @*BigBen*, [`pd.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) has a `datetime_format` parameter.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('outputfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format= "dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_1', index=False, startrow=2)
```

*NB: This will format every datetime column in your dataframe.*

Output :

[image]

Comment: Yes cannot use strftime on the dataframe as will convert to string and Excel will also store as a string. Needing to keep dataframe format as datetime64[ns] so Excel still recognized as a formatted number.

Comment: I will keep only the first approach then. Thanks y'all ;)